# list index out of range:using try except gives a different result:Command line parser

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-except

I am trying to build a cli parser where it looks like "scriptName -s arg1 arg2 ... -d ...". So I'm trying to append all the data after -s into a list(and finally into a dictionary) and return it.

The following is the function I'm using:

```
def split_data(cli_args):
   dict_args = {}
   local_list = []
   for i in range(1,len(cli_args)):
        if(cli_args[i] == '-s'):
            try:
                i = i + 1
                while(cli_args[i] != '-d'):
                    print("while",(cli_args[i]))
                    local_list.append(cli_args[i])
                    i = i + 1
                    print("local_list",local_list)
                dict_args.update({"options" : local_list})
            except BaseException as err:
                print(str(err))
                break
    print(dict_args)
    return dict_args
```

The result gives:

```
while arg1
local_list ['arg1']
while arg2
local_list ['arg1', 'arg2']
list index out of range
{}
```

But if you were to wrap the `while` loop(the complete loop) in a `try: except:pass` the final dictionary retains the data, why?

```
while arg1
local_list ['arg1']
while arg2
local_list ['arg1', 'arg2']
list index out of range
{"options" : ['arg1', 'arg2']}
```

Is there a better way to address this problem, or module to handle command line arguments?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using python's argparse module. It does exactly this and much more. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html.

You can set up optional arguments. Boolean arguments. argument=value like arguments and even do some logic on them like aggregating values.

However, if you really want to do this:

```py
listargs = False
dict_args = {}
lst = []
for i in cli_args:
    if i == "-d":
        listargs = True
    if listargs:
        lst.append(i)
    if i == "-s":
        listargs = False
        dict_args["options"] = lst
        lst = []
```